# How to grep from the output and write the greped text to a file

Tags: bash, shell, grep

I want grep only the text after every http: line and write it to a file.
I have the current output from the output stream

```html
References

   1. https://soundcloud.com/sc-opensearch.xml
   2. https://m.soundcloud.com/search/sounds?q=L AME IMMORTELLE
   3. https://soundcloud.com/
   4. http://www.enable-javascript.com/
   5. https://soundcloud.com/search
   6. https://soundcloud.com/search/sounds
   7. https://soundcloud.com/search/sets
   8. https://soundcloud.com/search/people
   9. https://soundcloud.com/search/groups
  10. https://soundcloud.com/thomas-rainer/l-ame-immortelle-banish
  11. https://soundcloud.com/outtamyndxmetal-llc/lame-immortelle-the-heart
  12. https://soundcloud.com/cyberdelic-mind/l-me-immortelle-dark-mix-i
  13. https://soundcloud.com/sawthinzarhtaik/dort-drauben
  14. https://soundcloud.com/lagrima-negra/lagrima-tears-in-the-rain
  15. https://soundcloud.com/bathony/in-strict-confidence-zauberschlos-lame-immortelle-version
  16. https://soundcloud.com/jubej-thos/sirius-5-jahre-lame-immortelle
  17. https://soundcloud.com/virul3nt/lamme-immortelle-sag-mir-wann-shiv-r-remix
  18. https://soundcloud.com/outtamyndxmetal-llc/lame-immortelle-no-goodbye
  19. https://soundcloud.com/usefulrage/das-ich-dem-ich-den-traum
  20. http://help.soundcloud.com/customer/portal/articles/552882-the-site-won-t-load-for-me-all-i-see-is-the-soundcloud-logo-what-can-i-do-
  21. http://google.com/chrome
  22. http://firefox.com/
  23. http://apple.com/safari
  24. http://windows.microsoft.com/ie
  25. http://help.soundcloud.com/
```

and my code currently which is not greping is below

```
lynx --dump -listonly https://soundcloud.com/search/sounds?q=L%20AME%20IMMORTELLE | \
tr "\t\r\n'" '   "' | \
grep -i -o 'http......HERE I NEED THE GREP STUFF' | \
sed -e 's/^.*"\([^"]\+\)".*$/\1/g' \ >k.txt
```

Comment: no no space before //

Comment: i want the whole http:///...............    link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `grep -E`:

```
grep -i -oE 'https?://soundcloud\.com[^[:blank:]]*'
```

Comment: bro  what if i want only get the text starting with https://soundcloud.com/ ..........   i mean i dont want print the other sites links , how can we change the grep ???

Comment: and if it is also possible to remove https://soundcloud.com/sc-opensearch.xml
https://soundcloud.com/
https://soundcloud.com/search
https://soundcloud.com/search/sounds
https://soundcloud.com/search/sets
https://soundcloud.com/search/people
https://soundcloud.com/search/groups     anyway to do that using tr or sed ???

Comment: Try this one: `sed '/:\/\/soundcloud\.com[^[:blank:]]*search/d'`

Comment: working now :) you are really god of bash . thanks a lot man :*

Comment: more 5 lines are gone away

Answer (score 0):

It worked with

```html
lynx --dump -listonly https://soundcloud.com/search/sounds?q=L%20AME%20IMMORTELLE | \
    tr "\t\r\n'" '   "' | \
    grep -i -oE 'https?://[^[:blank:]]+' | \
    sed -e 's/^.*"\([^"]\+\)".*$/\1/g' \
>k.txt
```

i got the appropriate output

```html
https://soundcloud.com/sc-opensearch.xml
https://m.soundcloud.com/search/sounds?q=L
https://soundcloud.com/
http://www.enable-javascript.com/
https://soundcloud.com/search
https://soundcloud.com/search/sounds
https://soundcloud.com/search/sets
https://soundcloud.com/search/people
https://soundcloud.com/search/groups
https://soundcloud.com/thomas-rainer/l-ame-immortelle-banish
https://soundcloud.com/outtamyndxmetal-llc/lame-immortelle-the-heart
https://soundcloud.com/cyberdelic-mind/l-me-immortelle-dark-mix-i
https://soundcloud.com/sawthinzarhtaik/dort-drauben
https://soundcloud.com/lagrima-negra/lagrima-tears-in-the-rain
https://soundcloud.com/bathony/in-strict-confidence-zauberschlos-lame-immortelle-version
https://soundcloud.com/jubej-thos/sirius-5-jahre-lame-immortelle
https://soundcloud.com/virul3nt/lamme-immortelle-sag-mir-wann-shiv-r-remix
https://soundcloud.com/outtamyndxmetal-llc/lame-immortelle-no-goodbye
https://soundcloud.com/usefulrage/das-ich-dem-ich-den-traum
http://help.soundcloud.com/customer/portal/articles/552882-the-site-won-t-load-for-me-all-i-see-is-the-soundcloud-logo-what-can-i-do-
http://google.com/chrome
http://firefox.com/
http://apple.com/safari
http://windows.microsoft.com/ie
http://help.soundcloud.com/
```